# FSL Bus Problem in Xilinx FPGA Data Return

Tags: fpga, xilinx, c, verilog, microblaze

I wrote a custom IP peripheral in Verilog and interfaced it to MicroBlaze, using a hardware co-processor option. I can see the peripheral connected on the System Design Diagram. Everything compiles and the build is successful.

Now I can see on hyperterminal that data is being sent to FSL. But then it gets stuck, there is no return of data from FSL.

I will paste both my Microblaze C code and Verilog code. Kindly guide me if there is a problem in my program or a any other problem.

This is C code `Test_fsl.c`

```
#include "xparameters.h"
#include "mb_interface.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "xutil.h"
#include "xdmacentral.h"
#include "xdmacentral_l.h"
#include "xgpio.h"
#include "fsl.h"
#include "xbasic_types.h"

int main (void)
{
    // Printing a banner on the Hyper Terminal.
    print("\t#########################################\n\r");
    print("\t#                                       #\n\r");
    print("\t#      FSL Channel Reference Design     #\n\r");
    print("\t#      MicroBlaze Development Board     #\n\r");
    print("\t#                                       #\n\r");
    print("\t#########################################\n\r");
    print("\n\r\n\r");


    print("-- Entering main() --\r\n");
    int i;
    Xuint32 arr[64];
    for(i=0;i<64;i=i+1){
        putfsl(i,0);
        xil_printf("\t--Sent Number--%d\n\r",i);
    }
    for(i=0;i<64;i=i+1){
        getfsl(i,0);
        xil_printf("\t--Received Number--%d\n\r",i);
    }
    for(i=0;i<64;i=i+1)
        xil_printf("\r\n 0x%x",arr[i]);
    print("-- Exiting main() --\r\n");

    // Printing a banner on the Hyper Terminal.
    print("\t#########################################\n\r");
    print("\t#                                       #\n\r");
    print("\t#      FSL Channel Reference Design     #\n\r");
    print("\t#          finished successfully        #\n\r");
    print("\t#                                       #\n\r");
    print("\t#########################################\n\r");
    print("\n\r\n\r");

    return 0;
}
```

My verilog custom IP perpheral code is :

```verilog
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// video - module
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// IMPORTANT:
// DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE EXCEPT IN THE DESIGNATED SECTIONS.
//
// SEARCH FOR --USER TO DETERMINE WHERE CHANGES ARE ALLOWED.
//
// TYPICALLY, THE ONLY ACCEPTABLE CHANGES INVOLVE ADDING NEW
// PORTS AND GENERICS THAT GET PASSED THROUGH TO THE INSTANTIATION
// OF THE USER_LOGIC ENTITY.
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// ***************************************************************************
// ** Copyright (c) 1995-2008 Xilinx, Inc.  All rights reserved.            **
// **                                                                       **
// ** Xilinx, Inc.                                                          **
// ** XILINX IS PROVIDING THIS DESIGN, CODE, OR INFORMATION "AS IS"         **
// ** AS A COURTESY TO YOU, SOLELY FOR USE IN DEVELOPING PROGRAMS AND       **
// ** SOLUTIONS FOR XILINX DEVICES.  BY PROVIDING THIS DESIGN, CODE,        **
// ** OR INFORMATION AS ONE POSSIBLE IMPLEMENTATION OF THIS FEATURE,        **
// ** APPLICATION OR STANDARD, XILINX IS MAKING NO REPRESENTATION           **
// ** THAT THIS IMPLEMENTATION IS FREE FROM ANY CLAIMS OF INFRINGEMENT,     **
// ** AND YOU ARE RESPONSIBLE FOR OBTAINING ANY RIGHTS YOU MAY REQUIRE      **
// ** FOR YOUR IMPLEMENTATION.  XILINX EXPRESSLY DISCLAIMS ANY              **
// ** WARRANTY WHATSOEVER WITH RESPECT TO THE ADEQUACY OF THE               **
// ** IMPLEMENTATION, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO ANY WARRANTIES OR        **
// ** REPRESENTATIONS THAT THIS IMPLEMENTATION IS FREE FROM CLAIMS OF       **
// ** INFRINGEMENT, IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS       **
// ** FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.                                             **
// **                                                                       **
// ***************************************************************************
//
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Filename:          video
// Version:           1.00.a
// Description:       Example FSL core (Verilog).
// Date:              Tue Jul 12 10:03:57 2011 (by Create and Import Peripheral Wizard)
// Verilog Standard:  Verilog-2001
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Naming Conventions:
//   active low signals:                    "*_n"
//   clock signals:                         "clk", "clk_div#", "clk_#x"
//   reset signals:                         "rst", "rst_n"
//   generics:                              "C_*"
//   user defined types:                    "*_TYPE"
//   state machine next state:              "*_ns"
//   state machine current state:           "*_cs"
//   combinatorial signals:                 "*_com"
//   pipelined or register delay signals:   "*_d#"
//   counter signals:                       "*cnt*"
//   clock enable signals:                  "*_ce"
//   internal version of output port:       "*_i"
//   device pins:                           "*_pin"
//   ports:                                 "- Names begin with Uppercase"
//   processes:                             "*_PROCESS"
//   component instantiations:              "<ENTITY_>I_<#|FUNC>"
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//
// Definition of Ports
// FSL_Clk             : Synchronous clock
// FSL_Rst           : System reset, should always come from FSL bus
// FSL_S_Clk       : Slave asynchronous clock
// FSL_S_Read      : Read signal, requiring next available input to be read
// FSL_S_Data      : Input data
// FSL_S_Control   : Control Bit, indicating the input data are control word
// FSL_S_Exists    : Data Exist Bit, indicating data exist in the input FSL bus
// FSL_M_Clk       : Master asynchronous clock
// FSL_M_Write     : Write signal, enabling writing to output FSL bus
// FSL_M_Data      : Output data
// FSL_M_Control   : Control Bit, indicating the output data are contol word
// FSL_M_Full      : Full Bit, indicating output FSL bus is full
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//----------------------------------------
// Module Section
//----------------------------------------
module video 
  (
    // ADD USER PORTS BELOW THIS LINE 
    // -- USER ports added here 
    // ADD USER PORTS ABOVE THIS LINE 

    // DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE ////////////////////
    // Bus protocol ports, do not add or delete. 
    FSL_Clk,
    FSL_Rst,
    FSL_S_Clk,
    FSL_S_Read,
    FSL_S_Data,
    FSL_S_Control,
    FSL_S_Exists,
    FSL_M_Clk,
    FSL_M_Write,
    FSL_M_Data,
    FSL_M_Control,
    FSL_M_Full
    // DO NOT EDIT ABOVE THIS LINE ////////////////////
  );

// ADD USER PORTS BELOW THIS LINE 
// -- USER ports added here 
// ADD USER PORTS ABOVE THIS LINE 

input                                     FSL_Clk;
input                                     FSL_Rst;
output                                    FSL_S_Clk;
output                                    FSL_S_Read;
input      [0 : 31]                       FSL_S_Data;
input                                     FSL_S_Control;
input                                     FSL_S_Exists;
output                                    FSL_M_Clk;
output                                    FSL_M_Write;
output     [0 : 31]                       FSL_M_Data;
output                                    FSL_M_Control;
input                                     FSL_M_Full;

// ADD USER PARAMETERS BELOW THIS LINE 
// --USER parameters added here 
// ADD USER PARAMETERS ABOVE THIS LINE


//----------------------------------------
// Implementation Section
//----------------------------------------
// In this section, we povide an example implementation of MODULE video
// that does the following:
//
// 1. Read all inputs
// 2. Add each input to the contents of register 'sum' which
//    acts as an accumulator
// 3. After all the inputs have been read, write out the
//    content of 'sum' into the output FSL bus NUMBER_OF_OUTPUT_WORDS times
//
// You will need to modify this example for
// MODULE video to implement your coprocessor

// Total number of input data.
localparam NUMBER_OF_INPUT_WORDS  = 64;

// Total number of output data
localparam NUMBER_OF_OUTPUT_WORDS = 64;

// Define the states of state machine
localparam Idle  = 3'b100;
localparam Read_Inputs = 3'b010;
localparam Write_Outputs  = 3'b001;

reg [0:2] state;

// Accumulator to hold sum of inputs read at any point in time
reg [0:31] sum;

// Counters to store the number inputs read & outputs written
reg [0:NUMBER_OF_INPUT_WORDS - 1] nr_of_reads;
reg [0:NUMBER_OF_OUTPUT_WORDS - 1] nr_of_writes;

// CAUTION:
// The sequence in which data are read in should be
// consistent with the sequence they are written in the
// driver's video.c file

assign FSL_S_Read  = (state == Read_Inputs) ? FSL_S_Exists : 0;
assign FSL_M_Write = (state == Write_Outputs) ? ~FSL_M_Full : 0;

assign FSL_M_Data = sum;

always @(posedge FSL_Clk) 
begin  // process The_SW_accelerator
  if (FSL_Rst)               // Synchronous reset (active high)
  begin
     // CAUTION: make sure your reset polarity is consistent with the
     // system reset polarity
     state        <= Idle;
     nr_of_reads  <= 0;
     nr_of_writes <= 0;
     sum          <= 0;
  end
  else
  case (state)
    Idle: 
    if (FSL_S_Exists == 1)
    begin
      state       <= Read_Inputs;
      nr_of_reads <= NUMBER_OF_INPUT_WORDS - 1;
      sum         <= 0;
    end

    Read_Inputs: 
    if (FSL_S_Exists == 1) 
    begin
      // Coprocessor function (Adding) happens here
      sum         <= sum + FSL_S_Data;
      if (nr_of_reads == 0)
      begin
        state        <= Write_Outputs;
        nr_of_writes <= NUMBER_OF_OUTPUT_WORDS - 1;
      end
      else
      nr_of_reads <= nr_of_reads - 1;
    end

    Write_Outputs: 
    if (nr_of_writes == 0) 
      state <= Idle;
    else
      if (FSL_M_Full == 0)  nr_of_writes <= nr_of_writes - 1;
  endcase
 end

endmodule
```

I don't have any return of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<64;i=i+1){
    getfsl(i,0);
    xil_printf("\t--Received Number--%d\n\r",i);
}
```

You are overwriting your loop counter `i` with the result of the FSL channel.

You need to create another variable and do something like:

```
for(i=0;i<64;i=i++){
    getfsl(val,0);
    arr[i] = val;
    xil_printf("\t--Received Number--%d got %8X\n\r", i, val);
}
```